# Prove that a group generated by two elements of order $2$, $x$ and $y$, is isomorphic to $D_{2n}$, where $n = |xy|.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

I am completely stuck at the question

> Let $G$ be a finite group and let $x$ and $y$ be distinct elements of order 2 in $G$ that generate $G$. Prove that $G \cong D_{2n}$, where $n = |xy|.$

I have proved that

> Let $x$ and $y$ be elements of order 2 in any group $G$. If $t = xy$ then $tx = xt^{-1}$.

Can I get some hints?

Comment: It seems that the title became different!

Comment: The same question was already asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160168/prove-a-group-generated-by-two-involutions-is-dihedral).

Comment: @BabakS. I don't think so though the title of the above link would be more appropriate. Anyway, someone would re-edit the title properly if necessary.

Comment: $\langle x, y \mid x^2 = y^2 = 1 \rangle$ is easily seen to be an infinite group. If you do not know though the use of presentations please do not use them!

Comment: ~>_<~ @PVAL I don't know though the use of presentations, but I didn't use them neither!

Comment: @BabakS. The group in the title now is not the Klein four group. There are irreducible words of arbitrary length of the form $xyxyxyxy\dots$. The group is infinite and usually referred to as the infinite dihedral group, with $xy$ and $y$ to be taken as the generators in the usual presentation of the infinite dihedral group.

Comment: @PVAL: What I commented was that the earlier title is good to think appropriately about the group. At the first sight, one might be confused seeing this edited one with Klien four group, if he/she didn't follow the rest.

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160168/prove-a-group-generated-by-two-involutions-is-dihedral

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Take the homomorphism that sends $xy$ to a rotation, and $y$ to a reflection. Show that this homomorphism is an isomorphism.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that. But the problem is $x,y$ both has order 2, but $r$ does not.

Comment: the analogy of $r$ is $xy$, which has the desired order.

Comment: Yes, the point you noted is right. Indeed, that was $x$ and $y$ faults not to commute. :-)

Answer (score 6):

By introducing the letter $t$, you have proven that you group can be written as a quotient of the dihedral group of order $2n$, $D_{2n}=\langle x, t; x^2, t^n, x^{-1}tx=t^{-1}\rangle$ (can you see why?). It also proves that every element has the form $xt^i$ or $t^i$. If the quotient was non-trivial then there would exist some integer $i$ with $0<i<n$ such that either $xt^i=1$ or $t^i=1$. However, $t^i\neq 1$ (why?). So $xt^i=1$, and so $x=t^i$. Can you see the required contradiction which completes the proof?

Comment: Complete source for the problem (+1). Thanks for the edit you made for me below. (-:

Comment: "It also proves that every element has the form $xt^i$ or $t^i$". Just curious, how about $t^ix$?

Comment: @yoyostein It works for $t^ix$ too. Just apply $x^{-1}tx=t^{-1}$. So what do you think $t^ix$ is equal to?

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I like the following presentation for $D_{2n}$:

$$\langle x,y\mid x^n=y^2=(xy)^2=1\rangle$$ Now assume that the following presentation is given:
$$G=\langle x,y\mid x^2=y^2=(xy)^n=1\rangle$$ So we have:
$$
\begin{align*}
G=\langle x,y&\mid x^2=y^2=(xy)^n=1\rangle\\
\cong
\langle x,y,a&\mid x^2=y^2=(xy)^n=1,a=xy\rangle\\
\cong
\langle x,y,a&\mid x^2=y^2=(xy)^n=a^n=1,a=xy\rangle\\
\cong
\langle x,y,a&\mid x^2=y^2=a^n=1,a=xy\rangle\\
\cong
\langle x,y,a&\mid x^2=y^2=a^n=1,a=xy,(ay^{-1})^2=1\rangle\\
\cong
\langle x,y,a&\mid y^2=a^n=1,a=xy,(ay^{-1})^2=1\rangle\\
\cong
\langle y,a&\mid y^2=a^n=1,(ay^{-1})^2=1\rangle\\
\cong
\langle y,a,b&\mid y^2=a^n=1,(ay^{-1})^2=1,b=y^{-1}\rangle\\
\cong
\langle y,a,b&\mid y^2=a^n=1,(ay^{-1})^2=1,b=y^{-1},b^2=1\rangle\\
\cong
\langle y,a,b&\mid a^n=1,(ay^{-1})^2=1,b=y^{-1},b^2=1\rangle\\
\cong
\langle y,a,b&\mid a^n=b^2=(ab)^2=(ay^{-1})^2=1,b=y^{-1}\rangle\\
\cong
\langle y,a,b&\mid a^n=b^2=(ab)^2=1,b=y^{-1}\rangle\\
\cong
\langle a,b&\mid a^n=b^2=(ab)^2=1\rangle
\end{align*}$$
Which is $D_{2n}$.

Comment: Wow, impressive, thanks Babak! But I have a question at the very beginning - how could you rule out $yx, xyx$ as elements of $G$?

Comment: $(xy)^2=1$ so $xyxy=1$ so $xyx=y^{-1}$ ans since $y=y^{-1}$ so $xyx=y$.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't follow - I only know that $x^2 = y^2 = xxyy = 1$. How can I get $xyxy = 1$?

Comment: @Tumbleweed: In fact we should know the following points before. Using these points, the presentation, I wrote at the beginning does make senses. That is: $$x=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 &\cdots &n \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$y=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-2 &n-1 & n\\
  1 & n & n-1 & \cdots &4 &3 &2\\
  \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Yikes! +1 for all the formatting!

Comment: You need to prove that every quotient is also a dihedral group (or is cyclic)...

Comment: (And I hope you don't mind my formatting edit...)

Comment: @user1729: Thanks for editing, but I thought that if I could make the group $G$ to have the same presentation as $D_{2n}$, then the problem is solved.

Comment: @BabakS. I think the best way to understand why you need this additional step is to consider the following question: Prove that every group which is generated by two elements $a$ and $b$ which each have order four and whose product has finite order at least three is infinite. This is not true, but your logic would prove that it was (the problem being homomorphic images). This is because these groups have presentation $\langle a, b; a^4, b^4, (ab)^n, \mathbf{r}\rangle$ for $n\geq 3$. You need to think about what is contained in the set **r**. (Note: If **r** is empty these groups are infinite).

Comment: @user1729: you mean that we need to show all conditions in von Dyck's substitution theorem are satisfied?

Comment: @BabakS. I am not sure what von Dyck's substitution theorem is, but my point is that the conditions this question gives you also hold for all homomorphic images of your group. It is a quirk of dihedral groups that their quotients are either dihedral or cyclic. But you need to prove this quirk...

Answer (score 1):

We call the two elements $s$, $t$ instead, so $G=\langle s,t\rangle$.

Note that $G=\langle st, t\rangle$ since $(st)t=s$. Since $G$ is finite, $st$ has a finite order, say $m$, so that $(st)^m=1_G$. We also have $[(st)t]^2=s^2=1$.

We claim that there are no other relations, other than $(st)^m=t^2=[(st)t]^2=1$.

Suppose to the contrary $sts=1$. Then $sstss=ss$, i.e.\ $t=1$, a contradiction. Similarly if $ststs=1$, $tsststsst=tsst$ implies $s=1$, a contradiction. Inductively, $(st)^ks\neq 1$ and $(ts)^kt\neq 1$ for any $k\geq 1$.

Thus $$G\cong D_{2m}=\langle a,b|a^m=b^2=(ab)^2=1\rangle.$$