# Order of 2-generated finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G=\left<a,b\right>$ be a finite group. What can I say about the order of $G$ with respect to the orders of $a$ and $b$?

Is it true that $|G|\leq |a||b|$, or are there any counterexamples?

What if $\{a,b\}$ forms a minimal generating set for $G$ (i.e. $\left<a\right>$,$\left<b\right>\ne G$)?

Comment: There are (by necessity, countably) infinite groups generated by two elements of order two.

Comment: Every dihedral group is generated by two elements of order two.

Comment: @lulu. I'm assuming $G$ is finite.

Comment: So, add a relation of the form $(ab)^n=e$.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487128/prove-that-a-group-generated-by-two-elements-of-order-2-x-and-y-is-isomo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only know the orders of $a$ and $b$, this gives you basically no upper bound for $|G|$ in general.

For example, a finite group $G$ is dihedral if and only if $G = \langle a,b \rangle$  for $|a| = |b| = 2$. In this case $G$ has order $2n$, where $n = |ab|$.

Also, any finite simple group $G$ is generated by two elements. It is conjectured (and known to be true in many cases) that for a finite simple group $G$ we have $G = \langle a,b \rangle$ for some $a, b \in G$ with $|a| = 2$ and $|b| \in \{3,5,7\}$.