# Seeking examples of finite, higher then $|a| \cdot |b|$ order groups generated by finite order generators

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I read this question:

[Order of 2-generated finite group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3552412/order-of-2-generated-finite-group)

And I'm looking to find an example of generators $a$ and $b$ that will produce a group $G = \langle a,b \rangle$ that will fulfill the following **strict** inequality:

$$|a| \cdot |b| < |G| = |\langle a,b \rangle |< \infty$$

I tried to find abstract examples by testing different commutation relations between $a$ and $b$. But I either got that my trial implies that $[a,b] = 0$ and then $|G| = |a|\cdot|b|$, or that the $G$ is of infinite order.

I'd also be interested in thinking of examples with more then 2 generators that will fulfill similar properties, something like:

$$|a| \cdot |b| \cdot |c| < |G| = |\langle a,b,c \rangle |< \infty$$

Comment: Are you trying to find examples satisfying the _strict_ inequality?

Comment: The smallest example is of order $6$ so it is surprising that you could not find it. The linked post gives examples (the dihedral groups) so why do you think your question is not a duplicate?

Comment: The alternating group $A_4$ of order $12$ satisfies the strict inequality. It can be generated by $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,2)(3,4)$.

Comment: To generalize, consider $G=A_4\times(\mathbb{Z}_2)^n$.

Comment: Each of the dihedral groups $D_n$ of order $2n$ is generated by two elements (reflections) of order $2$.

Comment: Oh yes @durianice I am seeking for examples satisfying the strict inequality, thanks for thinking about it.