# Let $G$ be a finite group and let $x$ and $y$ be distinct elements of order 2 in $G$ that generate $G$. Prove that $G\cong D_{2n}$, where $n=|xy|.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $x$ and $y$ be distinct elements of order 2 in $G$ that generate $G$. Prove that $G \cong D_{2n}$, where $n = |xy|.$

**My attempt** : This  question already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487128/prove-that-a-group-generated-by-two-elements-of-order-2-x-and-y-is-isomo).But  i have different approach

Im thinking about different answer

**My answer** : Since every element  of $G$ can be written as  $x^a (xy)^b$ for $ 0 \le a\le 2$ and $0 \le b \le n$

let  define a function  $f : D_{2n} \to G $ by $$f(s^ar^b)=x^a(xy)^b$$

Now we have to prove that  $f$ is homomorphism

proof : Take $ s^ar^b$   and $s^c r^d \in D_{2n}$

$f(s^ar^b.s^cr^d)= f(s^{a+c}r^{b+d})= x^{a+c}(xy)^{b+d}$

After that im not able to proceed further

Comment: Why does $rs=sr$?

Comment: that will represent abelian group @lhf   but    i have not written $rs=sr$?

Comment: Why does $f(s^ar^b.s^cr^d)= f(s^{a+c}r^{b+d})$ ?

Comment: @lhf     $(s^a.s^c )=s^{a+c}$  and $ r^b.r^d=r^{b+d}$

Comment: So you have used $rs=sr$.

Comment: okss  got its  now   $rs =sr  ^{-1}$  so we have   $f(s^ar^b.s^cr^d)= f(s^{a+c}r^{d-b})= x^{a+c}(xy)^{d-b}$

Comment: And what if $c=0$? Then you are claiming that $s^ar^br^d$, which is clearly equal to $s^ar^{b+d}$, is also equal to $s^ar^{d-b}$. So you are claiming that $r^{b+d}=r^{d-b}$ for *all* $b$ and $d$. That seems unlikely. You are going to have to consider different cases depending on whether $c=0$ or $c=1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin if $c=0$ , then  $f(s^ar^{d-b})=x^a(xy)^{d-b}= x^a(xy)^bx^0(xy)^d=f(s^ar^b)f(s^0r^d)$

if $c=1$ , then  $f(s^{a+1}r^{d-b})=x^{a+1}(xy)^{d-b}= x^{a}(xy)^bx^1(xy)^d=f(s^ar^b)f(s^1r^d)$

Comment: If $c=0$, then $(s^ar^b)(s^cr^d)$ is **not** equal to $s^ar^{d-b}$ (except in the special case that $n$ is even and $b=\frac{n}{2}$). Your entire reply is based on an incorrect assertion, and as such is worthless.