# Proof verification of Dummit and Foote exercise 1.6.24

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

**Problem 1.6.24 in D&F:**

> Let $G$ be a finite group and let $x$ and $y$ be distinct elements of order $2$ in $G$ that generate $G$. Prove that $G \cong D_{2n}$, where $n = |xy|$.

**My proof:**
If $t = xy$, then $tx = xyx =  xt^{-1}$. Thus, $t$ and $x$ satisfy the same relations as $D_{2n}$ where $n = |t|$. The elements $t$ and $x$ clearly generate $G$ because $G = \left< x, y \right>$ and $y = xt$. Summarizing, we have shown
$$
G = \left< t, x \mid t^n = x^2 = e, tx = xt^{-1} \right>
$$

**My question:**
Could you please check my proof to make sure it is sound (maybe suggest other simpler proofs)?

Thanks!

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487128/prove-that-a-group-generated-by-two-elements-of-order-2-x-and-y-is-isomo?rq=1)

Comment: @kabenyuk -- After a quick skim of that question, I couldn't find any proof that resembled mine.

Comment: The question from the link already contains your reasoning. The most important thing I wanted to say is that you have no definition of group $D_n$. Therefore you should start with it.

Comment: @kabenyuk -- Ah, yes, my mistake... $D_{2n}$ is the dihedral group of order $2n$, and has presentation $D_{2n}= \langle r,s \mid r^{n}=s^{2}=1, rs=sr^{-1} \rangle$