# Group classification generated by two elements

Tags: group-theory

Classify groups that are generated by two elements $x$ and $y$ of order 2.

Could someone help me please ?

Comment: Wow! That's a task...do you have *any* ideas? Have you seens Coxeter groups, dihedral groups...?

Comment: Hint in the spirit of DonAntonio's comment: Think about the generators' product $xy$. Also, if you know finitely presented groups, they might help.

Comment: @DonAntonio I have seen the group that you mentionned

Comment: @m_l That is the hint that I was given in the text..

Comment: @user43418 Which have you seen, dihedral groups or Coxeter groups in general? Have you seen finite presentations for dihedral groups?

Comment: @m_l I have seen dihedral groups. The only thing that I have send related to Coxeter, is the Todd-Coxeter algorithm.

Comment: @m_l If you could write a complete solution, I would highly appreciate it since I have another problem of the same style and would like to have some sort of solution I can work with in order to solve it. Thank you

Comment: A complete answer can be quite a feat: just think that any finite dihedral group can be written as a group generated by two involutions. Even more interesting, the infinite dihedral group is $\;\langle x,y\;;\;x^2=y^2=1\rangle \cong C_2*C_2\;$ , so even free products get into the game...

Comment: This is essentially the same as... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160168/prove-a-group-generated-by-two-involutions-is-dihedral  [An element of order 2 is called an *involution*.]

Comment: I agree with Bill Cook. It also also a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487128/prove-that-a-group-generated-by-two-elements-of-order-2-x-and-y-is-isomo) (perhaps I should say "**Hint**: [This old question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487128/prove-that-a-group-generated-by-two-elements-of-order-2-x-and-y-is-isomo) gives you your answer. Can you see why?", as the fact that they are the same is a nice exercise).

Answer (score 2):

This will not be a full answer, although the details I leave out shouldn't be too hard to fill in.

Consider the finitely presented group $G = \langle a, b : a^2 = b^2 = 1 \rangle$. Let $X = \langle x, y \rangle$ be a group with $x,y$ of order $2$. The groups you want to classify are the factor groups of $G$, since
$$ G \rightarrow X : a \mapsto x,~ b \mapsto y$$
is a homomorphism. Thus your task is to analyse the kernel of this homomorphism. If $y(xy)^k = 1$, then $(xy)^k=y$, so $(xy)^{2k} = 1$. Similarly, if $(xy)^kx=1$, then $(xy)^{2k}=1$. This yields that if $xy$ has infinite order, then $G \cong X$. You now need to consider the groups where $xy$ has finite order, i.e. groups of the form
$$ \langle a,b : a^2 = b^2 = (ab)^k = 1 \rangle $$
for some natural number $k$. (Are the generators supposed to be distinct elements? This is something you should watch out for.)

Comment: The OP asked for a complete solution though ;)

Comment: He did, but the question very much seemed like a homework problem. This is why I did not write a detailed answer that can just be copied without giving it some thought.

That being said, my answer really doesn't leave much to be done.

Edit: I just noted a downvote on the answer. Is there anything wrong with it?