# Number of non isomorphic groups of order $122$, My attempt through Sylow theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

$|G|=122 = 2 . 61$

No. of sylow $2$ subgroups $= 1$ or $61 = n_2$

No. of sylow $61$ subgroups $= 1 = n_{61}$

Let the group of order $61$ be $H_{61}$ and the group of order $2$ be $H_2$

Then : clearly both $H_{61}$ and $H_2$ are cyclic.

and if $a ∈ H_2  ⋂ H_{61}$

then, since $|a|$ must divide simultaneously both $2$ and $61$

hence, $H_{61}  ⋂ H_2 = \{{e}\}$

Since, $n_{61}=1$ hence, $H_{61}$ is normal and $( H_{61}  H_2 )$ is a subgroup $.....(1)$

Now, $|  H_{61}  H_{2} | = 61 . 2 = 122  ..... (2)$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ :$ H_{61}  H_2  = G ........ (3)$

Since $G = H_2 H_{61}$ and $|G|=122 = |H_2||H_{61}|$, there cannot be any more subgroups of order $2$. Hence $n_2$ must be equal to $1$

Hence, from $(1), (2), (3) : G = H \times K ≅ H ⊕ K ≅ \mathbb Z_2 ⊕ Z_{61} ≅ Z_{122}$

> What could have gone wrong in my method? Why am I not getting $D_{61}$ as an answer too?

**EDIT :** A theorem from Gallian says this :

If a group $G$ is the internal direct product of a finite nymber of subgroups $H_1,H_2, \cdots H_n$, then

$G \approx H_1 \oplus H_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus H_n$

Hence, here $H_2 \approx Z_2$ and $H_{61} \approx Z_{61}$ .

Hence, $G = H \times K \approx H \oplus K \approx Z_2 \oplus Z_{61} \approx Z_{122}$

Where could I have gone wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's not clear to me whence you derive that $G$ is the direct sum of those two groups. It can be a semidirect product as well (hence the $D_{61}$).

Comment: oh okay .. The book which I read did not mention the case of semi direct products as of now.

Comment: However, a theorem from Gallian says this :  if a group $G$ is the internal direct product of a finite nymber of subgroups $H_1,H_2, \cdots H_n$, then $G \approx H_1 \oplus H_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus H_n$

Comment: Hence, here $H_2 \approx Z_2$ and $H_{61} \approx Z_{61}$ . Hence, $G = H \times K \approx H \oplus K \approx Z_2 \oplus Z_{61} \approx Z_{122}$

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. You mistakenly concluded that $n_2=1$. This is false in general (e.g., the case of $D_{61}$). You cannot conclude $n_2=1$ from what you have before it.

Comment: oh okay .. but since $G = H_2 H_{61}$ and $|G|=122 = |H_2||H_{61}|$, there cannot be any more subgroups of order $2$. Hence $n_2$ must be equal to $1$

Comment: @VHP: That's not true. Consider $D_{61}$. If $f$ denotes a flip about one of the axes of symmetry, and $r$ denotes rotation (say clockwise), then $\langle f\rangle$ is a subgroup of order $2$, but so are $\langle r^k f\rangle$ for every $k$.

Comment: @Bungo True that . I guess I have made some error in this inference. Can you help me point it out ? $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$

>since $G = H_2 H_{61}$ and $|G|=122 = |H_2||H_{61}|$, there cannot be any more subgroups of order $2$. Hence $n_2$ must be equal to $1$

Comment: Oh maybe that extra subgroup of order $2$ is embedded inside $ H_2 H_{61} $ right?

Comment: @VHP: Your inference is valid if $G = H_2 H_{61}$ is a direct product. The reason for this is that if $h \in H_2$ and $k \in H_{61}$, then $(h,k)(h,k) = (h^2, k^2)$ and this will be $(1,1)$ only if $k = 1$. But $H_2 H_{61}$ is not a direct product unless BOTH of $H_2$ and $H_{61}$ are normal subgroups of $G$.

Comment: Got it . Thank you @Bungo :-) . So from here, I will conclude that if $n_2=1$, then $G \approx Z_{122}$ else, if $n_2=2$, then $G \approx ... $ . So, how should I infer $D_{61} $ after this step ?

Comment: @VHP: Can you show that if $n_2 \neq 1$, then any two distinct elements of order $2$ will generate $H_{2}H_{61}$. There is a general theorem that any finite group generated by two elements of order $2$ (which are called involutions) is dihedral. Of course, that just kicks the can down the road unless you have already proved that theorem :-) See, e.g.: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160168/prove-a-group-generated-by-two-involutions-is-dihedral

Comment: @VHP: Or, you can try to prove directly that the group must satisfy the defining relations for $D_{61}$: namely, it is generated by two elements $r,s$ which satisfy $r^{61} = 1$, $s^2 = 1$, and $s^{-1}rs = r^{-1}$.

Comment: @Bungo, I get it. Thank you very much. If you consider posting an answer, I shall accept it :-)

Comment: @VHP: OK, will do, since this comment thread has become quite long :-)

Comment: alrighto :-) @MikeMiller Thank you for your comments as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that $G = H_2 H_{61}$, but this is not a direct product unless $H_2$ is normal, or equivalently, $n_2 = 1$.

If $G = H_2 H_{61}$ is a direct product, then its elements are (under the appropriate isomorphism) ordered pairs of the form $(h,k)$ where $h \in H_2$ and $k \in H_{61}$. If we have $(h,k)(h,k) = (1,1)$ for some element $(h,k)$, then by definition of multiplication in a direct product, this means $(h^2, k^2) = (1,1)$, which is true if and only if $h^2 = 1$ and $k^2 = 1$. Since $k \in H_{61}$ this forces $k=1$, so $(h,k) = (h,1)$. In other words, the only element of $H_2 H_{61}$ with order $2$ is the nonidentity element of $H_2$, or putting it another way, $H_2$ is the unique (hence normal) subgroup of order 2.

But note that $D_{61}$ is also expressible in the form $H_2 H_{61}$. The difference here is that $H_2$ is not normal. Indeed, if $f$ denotes a flip about one of the axes of symmetry, and $r$ is a rotation by one position (say clockwise), then $\langle r^k f\rangle$ is a subgroup of order 2 for every $k$, so $n_{2} = 61$.

It remains to check that $D_{61}$ is the only group (up to isomorphism) of the form $H_2 H_{61}$ where $H_{61}$ is normal and $H_2$ is not.

To do this, one option is to note that if $n_2 = 61$, then I can certainly choose two distinct elements of order $2$. If I can show that $G$ is generated by these two elements, then I can conclude that $G$ must be dihedral, because [any finite group generated by two involutions is dihedral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160168/prove-a-group-generated-by-two-involutions-is-dihedral). However, if you haven't already proved that result, then this just kicks the can down the road.

Another option is to try to prove directly that $G$ must satisfy the defining relations for $D_{61}$: namely, it is generated by two (not necessarily unique) elements $r$ and $s$ which satisfy $r^{61} = 1$, $s^2 = 1$, and $s^{-1}rs = r^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you don't mind if I add a second answer. This is something of a side note and I don't want to clutter the main answer with it, but I think it might help clarify an issue you raised in the comments.

If $G = H_2 H_{61}$, and $H_2$ is not normal, you asked where the other elements of order $2$ are hiding. Let's explore this a bit.

First, note that $H_2$ is a subgroup of order $2$, and $H_{61}$ is a subgroup of order $61$. Their intersection is the identity. So, between them, they account for $62$ elements out of $122$: in other words, $|H_2 \cup H_{61}| = 62$. (Note that $H_2 \cup H_{61}$ is just a set, not a group.)

Now consider the set of all the remaining elements: $S = G \setminus (H_2 \cup H_{61})$. What are the orders of the elements in $S$? There two cases: either $H_2$ is normal or it is not. ($H_{61}$ is always normal since it has index 2.)

**Case 1**: $H_2 \lhd G$. In this case, $H_2$ contains the only element of order $2$, and $H_{61}$ contains the only elements of order $61$. Additionally, the identity is not in $S$, so by Lagrange's theorem, all the elements in $S$ must have order $122$. We conclude that $G$ is cyclic, and an element generates $G$ if and only if it is in $S$.

**Case 2**: $H_2$ is not normal. In this case, $G$ cannot be cyclic, because cyclic $\implies$ abelian $\implies$ all subgroups are normal. Therefore there are no elements of order $122$. As before, $H_{61}$ contains the only elements of order $61$, and the identity is not in $S$. Therefore all elements in $S$ must have order $2$. Since $|S| = 122 - 62 = 60$, this means we have found $60$ additional subgroups of order $2$, which along with the original $H_2$ gives us $61$ total.